# Is there a way to create intents and entities without the IBM Watson Conversation toolkit?

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson

I want to train the Watson Conversation service without using the toolkit? I want the chatbot to be trained by code.

I want to develop a system from which the administrator of a web page can edit or create intents and entities, so that in this way I do not have to be the one to edit if something is wanted to change. IBM Watson Virtual Agent is something similar to what I want to create

Comment: I don't think this is the ideal format, perhaps explain more in-depth?

Comment: @Scheme I want to develop a system from which the administrator of a web page can edit or create intents and entities, so that in this way I do not have to be the one to edit if something is wanted to change. IBM Watson Virtual Agent is something similar to what I want to create

Comment: Feature requests should be directed to IBM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own tooling or integration into conversation using the Workspace API.

https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#workspaces